# Why is function call terminating the debug process on IDA Freeware?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida, ghidra

I am solving a Reverse Engineering capture the flag challenge where I have to find a flag in the format flag{thisistheflag}. Below is the link to a GitHub Repository that contains the given exe file that I have to reverse engineer.

https://github.com/davepatel3/captureTheFlagReverseEngineering

When I try to execute the binary file for the exe, I just get "Error Code 1". Looking at the graph view on IDA pro allows me to see I have to switch the jnz to a jz, as shown in the image below.
[image: This image just shows the IDA Freeware graph view of the jnz to jz switch in the first block and the line with the issue.]
The line in particular I am stuck on is the call ds:atoi line. When I use debugger and step over this line the program immediately terminates indicating there is an error in that function, which I likely have to fix. I am quite new to assembly and CTF in general so I have minimal idea of how I can go about this. To best help with this issue I think it would be a good idea to go the the github link I provided and actually open the exe in your local IDA/Ghidra and see for yourself.

I have tried deleting the function entirely which just causes some memory issues. I have also tried to hardcode the return value of the function to see if that would cause the error to not occur. Neither of these solutions seem to work though. The only other solution I can think of is modifying the assembly code, which I have no clue how to do.

Comment: An RE CTF does **not** require you to path the code in general. In fact that's cheating and serious challenges are structured in a way that patching is useless (i.e. by implementing simple encryption). In this case, you are forcing the program to assume it has a specific condition (I don't want to say more) which it likely hasn't. This will make `atoi` fault and the debug terminate. x86dbg will tell you exactly what instruction faulted but that's to no use for this CTF. All you have to do is understand what the program is doing and feed it what it wants to be fed.

Comment: @MargaretBloom So I am trying a different approach by using Ghidra and trying to understand the code. I have identified the entry function and a function named FUN_00401400 as being important to the overall functionality. I have also identified a few important variables. But I am kind of stuck here. I have went through the important functions and analyzed the code (important variables, checking the hexadecimal and string views, etc...) but I do not know what manipulation I can even do to get to the flag. Can you give me a bit of a hint on what steps I can try to get to a potential flag?

Comment: Have you understood what the first block is checking? What about the second one? IDA did a good job naming the parameters, do you know what `argc` and `argv` are? If you don't, brush up on C programming.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I understand that the first block is checking whether the number of command line arguments is equal to 2. I also understand the second block is loading the second value in the argv array into ecx and converting it to an integer through ds:atoi. I am assuming the flag will be revealed by entering the right two command line arguments when executing the binary. I also have to track the edi variable in particular since that is the register associated with the flag. But I do not really know how to do this in IDA. I do not know how to interpret the stack/registers window though.